# Passing variables from php to shell script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have a php script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
    $IFO=750;
    $MDO=650;
?>
```

Now I want to take the variables $IFO and $MDO and pass them to a shell script so that if in the shell script I were to state:

```
echo $IFO
echo $MDO
```

I would get as an output

750
650

based on what it says in the php script.

What should I add to the php script or the shell script so that would work?

Comment: Pass them as arguments to the shell script?

Comment: One way may be as [zneak](http://stackoverflow.com/users/251153/zneak) mentioned is to call your shell script from php script itself using [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and pass  values as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are invoking the shell script as a subprocess in the PHP environment, you can use [`putenv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) to set these values:

```
putenv("IFO=$IFO");
putenv("MDO=$MDO");

// later, back at the farm
shell_exec('your_script');
```

This is best if you're dealing with a shell script that you can't modify that already refers to these names. It won't work if the shell script doesn't inherit the environment from PHP. If PHP is responsible for spawning the shell process, it should inherit the environment.

If PHP is not, you'll need a real sharing interface, such as IPC, files, or a message queue.